# issue replacing background video with image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Really frustrating problem I have encountered I have a full screen video playing in the background of my website however, I am designing the mobile layout and I am trying to replace the video with an image. However, it is not changing to the image on the landing page on the mobile- please see code below.

```
*/ CSS CODE */

@media(max-width:768px) {
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
.title h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 150px;
}
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.middle {
    height: 1400px;
    background-color: #1f1f20;
}
.social {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380%;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    align-items: center;
}

.bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
}
.Ishmayl-writeup {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #1f1f20;
}
.title video {
    display: none;
}
.title video {
    background: url('/images/3.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

}

```
@media(min-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.header video {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
@media(max-aspect-ratio:16/9) {
    .header {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .header video {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
}

*/ HTML CODE */

<body>
<section class="top" id="Home">
    <header>

        <div class="title">

            <div class="video">
                <video src="Video/Mountain.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted type="video/mp4"></video>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: why do you have `.title video` 2 times?

Comment: You set `.title video` to `display: none`, and then you are trying to apply a background image to that very same element … and now you wonder why you don’t see anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make two different classes for desktop and for mobile phone like this:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L3d82qov/)

```
<div class="title">
  <div class="video onlydesktop">
    <video src="Video/Mountain.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted type="video/mp4"></video>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="photo onlymobile">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.photo  {
    background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}


@media(min-width:769px) {

.onlydesktop{
  display:inline;
}
.onlymobile{
  display:none;
}

@media(max-width:768px) {

.onlydesktop{
  display:none;
}
.onlymobile{
  display:inline;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
}
.title h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    top: 150px;
}
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.middle {
    height: 1400px;
    background-color: #1f1f20;
}
.social {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380%;
    left: 30%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    align-items: center;
}

.bottom {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align: center;
}
.Ishmayl-writeup {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #1f1f20;
}
.title video {
    display: none;
}

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation and answer, I did as you said however with the .photo class when I change the demo link you inputted it does not change to another background image I wish to put there however when I revert to the image link you put in there it displays on mobile devices. I do not understand why it only displays the photo link you put and not allowing me to change it to another? @Arina